# Display image based on username file name in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on a site wherein in the user's profile, the user's photo will be displayed. The user could upload his/her photo using the upload photo button then it will automatically be renamed to the user's username and will be saved to the root folder named 'uploads'.

Now, I want to display the photo on the user's profile page but it won't show. I think it's because of the way I concatenate the file's name to its file extension or something else.

Here's my code so far:

**View.php**
`<img src="<?php echo base_url().'uploads/'.$userdata['usrname'];?>" width="200px" class="img-circle img-thumbnail" alt="avatar"><Br>`

**Controller**

```
public function files(){

      $nga = $this->session->userdata('username');

      $data['usrname'] = $nga, ".JPG";
}
```

Comment: Have you sanitized username input? What if someone's username has two words? String would be `"two words"`, but for img output is making working through http request/respond, it need to be `"two%20words" . ".jpg"`. Also, check upper/lower case of extension. Good way would be storing string of image location (default or uploaded) to table `users` as varchar column so you could call it in code easily.

Comment: @Tpojka username can't be two words. I think, upper/lower case won't matter in the file extension nor the file name, I tried it and the photo still works.

Comment: You've already dedicated full name of image to variable/element of array passed to view file. So try with: `<img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/'.$usrname);?>" width="200px" class="img-circle img-thumbnail" alt="avatar"><Br>`.

Comment: it gives me this error again: `Message: Undefined variable: usrname`

Comment: You need to load view file in method of controller too.

Comment: How do you load view file?

Comment: `$this->load->view('user_header');` or `$this->load->view('user_header',$data);`

Comment: Make variables available in your view(s) in way you load them before ` $this->load->vars($data);`. Check basics in [docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/loader.html#CI_Loader::vars).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <img src="<?php echo base_url().'uploads/'.$data['usrname'] = $this->session->userdata('username'). ".JPG";;?>" width="200px" class="img-circle img-thumbnail" alt="avatar"><Br>
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
$data['usrname'] = $nga, ".JPG";
```

Should be this (a dot instead of comma to concatenate):

```
$data['usrname'] = $nga . ".JPG";
```

Comment: I already figured it out. Tried that already but it still doesn't work. But thanks anyway :)